# Override `==` if overriding `hashCode`

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following class in dart...

```
class Color {
    final int value;
    const Color._internal(this.value);

    static const Color WHITE = const Color._internal(0);
    static const Color BLACK = const Color._internal(1);

    int get hashCode => value;
    String toString() => (this == WHITE) ? 'w' : 'b';
}
```

When I run the flutter analyze command I get the following error...

> info • Override `==` if overriding `hashCode` • lib/chess.dart:1584:13
>   • hash_and_equals

As a test I added the method

```
bool operator==(Object o) => true;
```

But then I got another analyzer problem....

> error • The constant map entry key expression type 'Color' can't
>   override the == operator • lib/chess.dart:44:3 •
>            const_map_key_expression_type_implements_equals

This is because the Color object is used as a key in a static const map...

```
static const Map<Color, List> PAWN_OFFSETS = const {
    BLACK: const [16, 32, 17, 15],
    WHITE: const [-16, -32, -17, -15]
};
```

So I am confused as to what my options are to prevent these analyzer issues.

If I remove the hashCode, the class wont work in a map...
If I add the == operator I just get a different error.

What is the best option?

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that Dart will need to assess the const Map during compile time. Since you have a user-generated object, it cannot do that, thus the error.

Your choices are:

1. Make your map non-const. You can use `bool operator ==(Object o) => true`if you wish, but proper style suggests over-riding both hashCode and == at the same time.
2. Do not use the override and use Color.value to pass through a const map<int, List> instead.

The following [GIST shows option 1](https://dartpad.dev/61f75527a2217a5ca53b501238e85a4d?null_safety=true) in DartPad. [The following issue in Flutter's Github helped me with the answer](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/38298).

Answer (score -1):

You cannot have two equal keys in a `Map`, and you are telling the compiler that any `Color` object is equal to any other `Color` object by stating:

```dart
bool operator==(Object o) => true;
```

This way, the compiler thinks `BLACK` and `WHITE` are the same thing. However, if you do something like this instead:

```dart
bool operator==(Object o) => o is Color && o.value == value;
```

the compiler will only consider two `Color` objects equal if their `value`s are equal. Therefore, it won't consider `BLACK` and `WHITE` to be equal anymore (since their values are different), and the issue should be solved.

Comment: This does not answer the question AT ALL. The return true is just a temporary test method definition....did you read the question?

Comment: Not quite true. If the map is not const, the compiler will use value to hash. If the map is const, the user-defined object will not compile anyway. It is good practice to do a proper override, however.